# What is the best way to implement Singleton Design Pattern in C# with performance constraint?

Tags: design-patterns

Please let me know what the best way to implement Singleton Design Pattern in C# with performance constraint?

Comment: What is the "performance constraint" you speak of?

Comment: I would want the fastest implementation. I have heard about an article on this site but do not remember the name. If someone knows, please post it here.

Answer (score 7):

Paraphrased from [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx):
There are various different ways of implementing the singleton pattern in C#, from 
Not thread-safe to a fully lazily-loaded, thread-safe, simple and highly performant version.

Best version - using .NET 4's Lazy type:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
  private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
      new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

  public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

  private Singleton()
  {
  }
}
```

It's simple and performs well. It also allows you to check whether or not the instance has been created yet with the [IsValueCreated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642334.aspx) property, if you need that.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Singleton 
{
    static readonly Singleton _instance = new Singleton();

    static Singleton() { }

    private Singleton() { }

    static public Singleton Instance
    {
        get  { return _instance; }
    }
}
```