# What is an efficient way to implement singleton pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

This question came up when I was going through a similar question for Java.
[What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Can we implement something similar in C#?

Comment: Check this [thread](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79/implementing-a-singleton-pattern-in-c) on Code Review

Comment: Possibly see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: whatever you find for java, there is probably a much better, less-code, more beautiful way of doing it in C#.

Comment: @HighCore The standard implementation of a singleton is likely going to look literally identical for both languages...if there is a difference, it's likely to be nominal.

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @servy even if it's exactly the same code, with the same lines made up of the same keywords and the same identifiers, C# is better.

Comment: @HighCore If it's the same, then by definition, it's not better.  It is the same.  If there were a language feature of C# that made this particular task much more effective than in Java, it might be worth commenting on, but as there isn't, I fail to see the point.

Comment: @servy there is no point, don't you see? I'm just kidding...

Answer (score 4):

You must have checked [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) by Jon Skeet

> All these implementations share four common characteristics, however:
>
> - A single constructor, which is private and parameterless. This    prevents other > >classes from instantiating it (which would be a violation of the pattern). Note that it >also prevents subclassing - if a singleton can be subclassed once, it can be subclassed >twice, and if each of those subclasses can create an instance, the pattern is violated. The factory pattern can be used if you need a single instance of a base type, but the exact type isn't known until runtime.
> - The class is sealed. This is unnecessary, strictly speaking, due to    the above point, but may help the JIT to optimise things more.
> - A static variable which holds a reference to the single created    instance, if any.
> - A public static means of getting the reference to the single created    instance, creating one if necessary.

```
public class Singleton 
{
    static readonly Singleton _instance = new Singleton();

    static Singleton() { }

    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get  { return _instance; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like `public static` more than `static public`.

Comment: @RahulTripathi it does not (assuming it's valid enough for it to compile). However, there is a convention to the ordering of modifiers like that, and `public static` is certainly the norm.

Comment: @TimS.:- Thanks a lot Sir. I will check that +1!

Answer (score 1):

common way to implement one

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {}
    static Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Singleton
 {
        private static Singleton instance = null;

        public static Singleton Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton ();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a few for you:

[Jon Skeet's](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html).

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902347/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-singleton-design-pattern-in-c-sharp-with-perfo).

And [this one](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) as well.

At the end of the day though, these are all pretty subjective so, you need to do what is best for you and what you are trying to accomplish.